# Compile a full project of TypeScript in IntelliJ

Tags: compilation, intellij-idea, typescript

I'm using TypeScript in my project and I have many .ts file, about 50 files.
I'm using IntelliJ, and a file watcher to compile on save.
The thing is that I want to compile the full project on command, and see if there are any errors on a full project compile (There are dependencies), is there a good way to do that?

Thanks
Gil Amran

Comment: I've managed to run an external tool from IntelliJ that runs a grunt that will compile the full project... But I see no errors this way... any other good way?

Comment: That would have been my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont use Idea to generate result js code.
Use Grunt tasks manager and Grunt-TS ([Grunt-TS](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-ts)) plugin by @Basarat.